# I need VBA code to sum columns individually below the last row of data

Tags: excel, vba, sum

I have no idea where to start - i have searched the board and thought i may have found a pseudo solution but to no avail.

This info may or may not be pertinent but I have 15 sheets - "Sheet1" I have set the Last Row as:

```
Sub filtertests()
Dim LastRow As Long

'Find the last row
LastRow = Range("A5").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
```

I have 9 of the other sheets (named "sheet2" through "sheet10") that have variations of 100 to 5000 rows, in which i need to sum column Y, Z, AA, AB and AC individually on each tab - two rows below the last data row.
Each data sheet is formatted the same, Header row in Row 5, actual data starts at A:

Tabs 10 through 15 do not have to be summed.

Comment: The best way to find the last row is `LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: Is this going to sum on the same page or on a summary page? And can you clarify "tabs"?

Answer (score -1):

Heavily commented so you can see what is happening.

```
Option Explicit                                                                                                     ' forces declaration of all variables

Sub filtertests()
    ' declare variable types
    Dim srcWB As Workbook: Set srcWB = ThisWorkbook
    Dim current_ws As Worksheet
    Dim summary_ws As Worksheet: Set summary_ws = srcWB.Worksheets("Summary")
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim sum As Integer
    Dim i As Long
    Dim i2 As Long
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim ws_count As Integer
    
    ws_count = srcWB.Worksheets.count
    
    summary_ws.Cells.Clear
    
    On Error Resume Next
    For i = 1 To ws_count
        For i2 = 1 To 6                                                                                 ' iterates through the columns
            Set current_ws = srcWB.Worksheets(srcWB.Worksheets(i).Name)                                 ' set the worksheet to work with
            lRow = current_ws.Cells(current_ws.Rows.count, "Y").End(xlUp).Row                           ' find the last row in column Y of the current worksheet
            Set rng = current_ws.Range(current_ws.Cells(2, i2 + 23), current_ws.Cells(lRow, i2 + 23))   ' set the range to sum (Y2 to the last row containing data in AC)
            sum = Application.WorksheetFunction.sum(rng)                                                ' sum the data range
            lRow = summary_ws.Cells(summary_ws.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row                           ' find the last row in column A of the summary_ws worksheet
            If i2 = 1 Then summary_ws.Cells(lRow + 1, i2) = srcWB.Worksheets(i).Name                    ' if the first iteration, store the sheet name
            If i2 > 1 Then summary_ws.Cells(lRow, i2) = sum                                             ' if not the first iteration, store the sum
        Next i2                                                                                         ' iterate to the next column in the worksheet
    Next i                                                                                              ' iterate to the next worksheet in the workbook
    
    With summary_ws                                                                                     ' do something with this range
        .Cells(1, 1) = "Worksheet"                                                                      ' set value of range.cells
        .Cells(1, 2) = "Sum (Y)"                                                                        ' set value of range.cells
        .Cells(1, 3) = "Sum (Z)"                                                                        ' set value of range.cells
        .Cells(1, 4) = "Sum (AA)"                                                                       ' set value of range.cells
        .Cells(1, 5) = "Sum (AB)"                                                                       ' set value of range.cells
        .Cells(1, 6) = "Sum (AC)"                                                                       ' set value of range.cells
    End With                                                                                            ' stop doing something with this range
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

As I understand your description, you are looking for something like this:

- Go through all the sheets of the workbook (if you analyze [these ~2000 similar topics](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=iterate+all+sheets), then the best way is to loop `For Each`), skip the sheets with indices 10..15.
- Find the last non-empty row on each of the sheets. This is also a [popular topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=last+row+on+the+sheets) - there are different ways to do this. I prefer to search for the first filled cell backwards. This method is criticized, called "too complicated" and "slow". I don't think so.
- Now let's check if this sheet has already been processed - if the formula for summing by column in the last row has been set. If this is not done, then each next run of the macro will add the summation formula over and over again. At a good level, it is necessary to check the presence of the formula in all columns Y, Z, AA, AB and AC. But we can only check one of them, for example Y.
- When all the checks are completed, insert the column summation formula into the required cells.

These formulas will be very similar, differ only in the letters of the column

```
=SUM(Y$6:Y5000)
=SUM(Z$6:Z5000)
=SUM(AA$6:AA5000), etc.
```

(This is for the case when the data on the sheet takes 5000 rows, for other sheets this value will be different)

Usually the compilation of such formulas in VBA is a problem. But we are using one easy trick. All these formulas in R1C1 format will be exactly the same - `=SUM(R6C:R[-3]C)`,  *sum all the values in the current column ​​from the 6th row to the row three rows above this cell*

Translated into VBA it looks like this:

```
Sub addSumms()
Const OUR_FORMULA As String = "=SUM(R6C:R[-3]C)"
Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        If ws.Index < 10 Or ws.Index > 15 Then ' "Tabs 10 through 15 do not have to be summed"
            lastRow = getLastNonEmptyRow(ws)
            If lastRow > 5 Then ' <6 - no data to calculate
                If ws.Range("Y" & lastRow).Formula2R1C1 <> OUR_FORMULA Then ' This sheet already contains formulas SUM()
                    lastRow = lastRow + 3 ' Or +2? Don't understand "two rows below the last data row"
                    ws.Range("Y" & lastRow & ":AC" & lastRow).Formula2R1C1 = OUR_FORMULA
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub
```

I used code like this to find the last non-empty row:

```
Function getLastNonEmptyRow(Optional ws As Worksheet) As Long
Dim rFound As Range
    If ws Is Nothing Then Set ws = Application.ActiveSheet
    Set rFound = ws.UsedRange.Find("*", LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
    If rFound Is Nothing Then
        getLastNonEmptyRow = 0
    Else
        getLastNonEmptyRow = rFound.Row
   End If
End Function
```

You can replace this with traditional `.End(xlUp).Row` or `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row` or any other

Comment: Someone marked this answer as not useful. I don't know what he meant, he didn't leave a comment. Probably could not read and understand 10 lines of VBA code. Especially for him, I supplemented the answer and translated it into English. I apologize to everyone who has to read the same thing twice.

Comment: Why do you need a function for last row?

Comment: Because I have this function in another module and even in another book - in my personal macro book, PERSONAL.XLSB. :-) There I collected a whole set of tools - universal functions and procedures for working with arrays, with ranges, with search and replace, different. And when I write new code, I just write one line - calling the right tool. But when I publish the code here, I have to extract the code from there, from the "my toolbox" and show it side by side, otherwise the program cannot be run without error.